# Poner contraeña a pdf con itext

Tags: c#, .net-core, itextsharp, itext

Creo el pdf a base de un html, entonces lo tengo en una variable buffer la cual necesito poner una contraseña, estoy usando la libreria itext y C#, se debe retornar por un base 64 pero no consigo que firme

```
            var passwordpropietario = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.UserPassword);
            var passwordusuario = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request.UserPassword);
            var properties = new EncryptionProperties();
            properties.SetStandardEncryption(passwordusuario, passwordpropietario, EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING | EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);
            var str = (string)null;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new PdfReader(memoryStream))
                        {
                            PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, ms, properties);

                            str = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
                            pdfOutPassword.PdfBase64 = str;
                            return pdfOutPassword;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mas o menos deberia ser así:

```
String userPassword = "user123";
String ownerPassword = "owner123";

//Crea instacia PDFWriter.
  PdfWriter pdfWriter = 
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
 
// Agrega proteccion con password.
  pdfWriter.SetEncryption(userPassword.getBytes(), 
            ownerPassword.GetBytes(),
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, 
            PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);

 //Open the document.
 document.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Un pequeño Ejemplo:

```
string WorkingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string InputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Test.pdf");
string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Test_enc.pdf");

using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles a tu respuesta: si bien puede ser útil al OP, necesitas detallar tu respuesta para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago así!

```
using (var input = new FileStream("C:/archivoOriginal.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var output = new FileStream("C:/archivoConContrasena.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
               {
                   var reader = new PdfReader(input);
                   PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true,"tucontraseña", "tucontraseña", PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
```